# asp.net webforms app trying to connect to database that isn't being referenced anywhere in code?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, connection, offline

I had a few old database on my server, so took the older, unused ones offline.

This has caused a very strange problem, in that my site is complaining about not being able to connect to one of these databases.

I have searched the entire code-base for the database name, as well as all the config files on the server, and none of them reference this database name, yet if I take if offline, I get an error?

I can't see from the error what is actually making the request to connect, apart from it looks like its related to the SQL Session Server.

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Database 'MyOldDatabaseName' cannot be
>   opened because it is offline.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection) +1953274
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4849707
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +194    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +2392
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +33
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +96
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +297
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async) +954
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) +32
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +141
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() +89
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.DoGet(HttpContext
>   context, String id, Boolean getExclusive, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan&
>   lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags) +516
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server session
>   database.]
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.ThrowSqlConnectionException(SqlConnection
>   conn, Exception e) +229
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.DoGet(HttpContext
>   context, String id, Boolean getExclusive, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan&
>   lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags) +649
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.GetItemExclusive(HttpContext
>   context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object&
>   lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags) +48
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem() +117 
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object
>   source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +487
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +66    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: I have checked the machine.config file, and there is no reference in there too. I've also removed any old dlls from my bin folder. Totally in sync with dev, where I don't even have a database of that name

Answer (score 1):

You know it's a web application. You can go to IIS, stop all web sites, take the database offline and see if the error appears. If you can't reproduce it, some web site is connecting to the database and you aren't checking its source code. You can then start the sites one by one until it breaks.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

did you Clean your solution? Try cleaning it and then rebuild it. Also , you need to check what happens when you bring that database back online.Check in your IIS for any Connection String that may be refering to this site.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server session database` indicates that you are/were using SQL Server to store session state. Look in your web.config for the `sessionState` element under `configuration -> system.web`.  If the `mode` attribute is set to `SQLServer`, then there will be a `sqlConnectionString` attribute with the connection string.  You can change the mode from `SQLServer` to `InProc` to move to an in memory solution and away from SQL Server.  For load balanced environments you'll have to stick with SQL Server or the in-memory State Server.

Answer (score 0):

Set your database online with **the MSSQL query below**:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database-name> SET ONLINE
```

In addition, **the MSSQL query below** set your database offline:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database-name> SET OFFLINE
```